# Insert data into a table from comma separated string (T-SQL)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have table with a integer column and the data as below:

4,89, 8, 1

How can I insert above integers in to a column.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved with a [Table Value Constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/table-value-constructor-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Example:

```
Select *
From (Values (1),(2),(3),(4)) tabA (ColA)
```

Answer (score 1):

Automatically:

```
DECLARE @DataSource TABLE
(
    [ColumnValue] INT
);

DECLARE @Input VARCHAR(MAX) = '4,89, 8, 1';

DECLARE @InputXML XML = CAST(N'<r><![CDATA[' + REPLACE(@Input, ',', ']]></r><r><![CDATA[') + ']]></r>' AS XML);

INSERT INTO @DataSource
SELECT RTRIM(LTRIM(Tbl.Col.value('.', 'INT'))) AS Code 
FROM @InputXML.nodes('//r') Tbl(Col)
```

Answer (score -2):

```
Select *
From (Values (1),(2),(3),(4)) table (ColumnA)
```

Comment: Please add a short description into your answer to make it more useful